# MSVCP140.dll initialization failed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dependency-management

My application throws this error on the start

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8DC378C34 (msvcp140.dll) in TimexLPRService.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
```

In Stack Frame control I see msvcp140.dll!mtx_do_lock(_Mtx_internal_imp_t *mtx, const xtime *target)

const xtime *target is null (it shows in locals control)

If I start application manually it tells I have error on startup (error code 0xc0000142).
I have msvcp140.dll and vcruntime140.dll near the executable

I build my application with Visual Studio 2019 and vcpkg

I want to know how I can debug this problem to understand what went wrong or what possible causes of such problem

Comment: The more code there is, the tougher it is to figure out what is causing the problem. I'd recommend making a temporary copy of your project and finding the smallest amount of code that causes the problem. At that point, you can also update your question with that code to get help.

Answer (score 0):

There can be different reasons.

### #1 <sup>(update)</sup>

You may have a null pointer exception somewhere:

```
Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000
```

To fix, try running your code using IDE's debugger, and it should break on the first access violation.

### #2

The "`MSVCP140.dll`" name is shared between multiple versions, for example MSVC 2015 and MSVC 2019.

As long as the latest redist is installed, there should be no problems.

But crashs happen, for example if:

- Your App was built with MSVC 2019.
- But an older version is installed on the system (like 2015 redist).
- Or, the correct redist is installed, but the wrong `.dll` version is placed beside your executable.

Comment: I install latest verstion of redist 2015-2022 (14.31) (beside .dll version 14.12). I delete beside dlls, but that doesn't help

Comment: @Simon if you run using IDE, maybe the `.dll` is beside IDE's executable. However, see above's update.

Comment: I try to start exe file itself and it failes with error message with code 0xc0000142. If I try to start debug ide asks to show path to mutex.c

Comment: In Stack Frame control I see msvcp140.dll!mtx_do_lock(_Mtx_internal_imp_t *mtx, const xtime *target)

Comment: const xtime *target is null (it shows in locals control)

Comment: @Simon If you walk down the stack, don't you see anything of your own project's or it's framework's methods/functions listed?

Comment: You should, because I don't think `msvcp140.dll` creates it's own thread.

Comment: However, most debuggers show all loaded modules (.dll files), I mean,

Comment: Once you are sure the right version of `.dll` files are loaded, search for issues in stack related to your own code (not anything inside said `.dll` file).

Comment: Yes, another dll from library, which I use, makes that call before even main starts

Comment: @Simon usually, not a single line of code runs before App's entry-point (main-function), but frameworks like `Qt` set their own entry, then call your main-function later.

Comment: Hence, if you did already check loaded modules' correctness (their path, with debugger's tools), it's an issue within library you mentioned.

Comment: I have Win32 project, may be that makes run some code before

Comment: @Simon no that makes no difference.